# Create two new columns from the Date column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently using Pandas and the DataFrame is a CSV file. I need to use the `Date` column to create additional columns:

I have filtered the `Date` column to get 2022/2021 information only using:

`df = df.loc[df["Date"].between("2022", "2021")]`

Currently I have:

| Date | Type | Initial | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | Bin | S | 5 |
| 2022 | Bin | S | 6 |
| 2022 | Bin | S | 9 |
| 2021 | Bin | B | 5 |
| 2021 | Bin | B | 7 |
| 2021 | Bin | B | 0 |

I am currently trying to get the following output:

| Type | 2022 | 2021 | Initial | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bin | 20 | 12 | S/B | 8 |

Comment: Is it possible to post few sample records of the CSV file?

Comment: Hi Alok, thanks for getting back,  unfortunately I cannot share the csv file, but the first table is a reflection of the structure of data that I'm working with

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question, this may help

```
df = df.groupby(by=['Date']).sum()
df['Difference'] = df.diff()['Number']
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my attempt:

```
dfx = df.groupby(['Type ','Date ']).agg({'Initial ':lambda x: '/'.join(x.unique()),'Number':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

output:

```
Type    Date    Initial     Number
Bin     2021    B           12
Bin     2022    S           20
```

then:

```
dfy = dfx.pivot(index=['Type ','Initial '], columns='Date ', values='Number').reset_index()
```

output:

```
Type    Initial     2021    2022
Bin     B           12.0    
Bin     S                   20.0
```

then:

```
dfz = dfy.groupby('Type ').agg({'Initial ':lambda x: '/'.join(x.unique()),2021:'sum',2022:'sum'}).reset_index()
```

output:

```
Type    Initial     2021    2022
Bin     B /S        12.0    20.0
```

now you can add difference:

```
dfz['difference'] = dfz[2022] - dfz[2021]
```

output:

```
Type    Initial     2021    2022    difference
Bin     B /S        12.0    20.0    8.0
```